# GIT или Maven? Что выбрать для Java?

Tags: java, git, maven

Здравствуйте, вопрос может быть не совсем корректный, но всё же интересно мнения бывалых. Работаю с Java, когда начал  изучение не думал о таких вещах как репозитории, контроль версий, а сейчас остро возникает вопрос - *git* или *Maven*?
Интересны за-против, минусы-плюсы.

Comment: Если вы задумались о таких вещах, как репозитории и контроль версий, то однозначно - git.

Comment: Здесь стоит задуматься о выборе, например, или между git и mercurial, или между maven и gradle...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Git - это система контроля версий исходного кода.

Maven - инструмент сборки проекта и управления зависимостями.

Их задачи совершенно разные, и вы смело можете использовать и то и другое.